# VimDiff: Change statusline color below the non-active file

Tags: vim

What's the way to change Vim statusline color when I use diff?

I.e., I successfully changed the statusline color below the active file (file_1.txt). It's light grey, and that's okay.

But how I can change the statusline color below the *non-active* file (file_2.txt)? Currently it's white text on black background, and I don't know how to change it.

[image]

```
" general
" -----------------------
" remove the top toolbar
set guioptions-=T

" window title
set titlestring=%t

" test wrapping etc
set linebreak
set formatoptions-=t

" diff
" -----------------------
" text wrap
autocmd FilterWritePre * if &diff | setlocal wrap< | endif

" maximize window and spread columns equally
if has("gui_running")
  if &diff
    autocmd VimResized * wincmd =
    autocmd GuiEnter * simalt ~x
  endif
endif

" statusline
" -----------------------
set laststatus=2
highlight statusline gui=NONE guibg=#eeeeee guifg=black

set statusline=%t               " tail of the filename
set statusline+=%=              " left/right separator

" encoding
set statusline+=%{(&fenc\ ==\ \"\"?&enc:&fenc).(&bomb?\"\ with\ BOM\":\"\")},\ "

set statusline+=%{&fileformat}  " line endings
set statusline+=%(,\ %R%)       " read only flag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StatusLine` hl-group is for the current selected window. And the `StatusLineNC` is for statusline in "Not Current" window. You can just define this group.

`:h StatusLineNC` to see the doc.